# R loop error: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to make a loop to explore the model combinations. So, I am doing the following:

```
# k=ncol(tmp1)-1
k = 5  ## example k without knowing "tmp1"

#number of models
M=2^k
#a matrix to store indicators/switch for predictors. Need two loops to do this (for loops)
incl_pred<-matrix(0,M,4)
tmpm=M
i=1
for(i in 1:k){
  tmpm=tmpm/(2)
  incl_pred[1:tmpm,i]=1
}
for(i in 2:k){
  tmpm=M
  for(j in i:k){
    incl_pred[((tmpm/2)+1):tmpm,j]=incl_pred[1:(tmpm/2),j]
    tmpm=tmpm/2
  }
}
```

But it is giving me two errors:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, 1:tmpm, i, value = 1) : subscript out of bounds

and

> Error in incl_pred[1:(tmpm/2), j] : subscript out of bounds.

Can you help me fix it?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set:

```
incl_pred<-matrix(0,M,k)
```

because your inner loop:

```
  for(j in i:k){
     incl_pred[((tmpm/2)+1):tmpm,j]=incl_pred[1:(tmpm/2),j]
```

is accessing up to `k` columns of `incl_pred`.